# Run a command if no match is found using AWK

Tags: awk, text-processing

I have two files that I need to run comparisons on in the first column.

File1

```
User1, misc info, stuff
User2, misc info stuff2
User3, misc info, more stuff
```

File2

```
User4, misc info, more stuff
User2, misc info, different stuff
```

First I need to test the col1 values in File2. If a col1 File2 value does not exist in File1, then that line gets removed. So after this first operation, the second file should look like this:

File2 after first operation:

```
User2, misc info, different stuff
```

After that I need to test the col1 values in File1. If a col1 File1 value does not exist in File2, then the entire line in File1 needs to be appended to File2. After this operation, the second file should look like this:

File2 after second operation:

```
User2, misc info, different stuff
User1, misc info, stuff
User3, misc info, more stuff
```

I see a lot of awk examples online, but many are about finding a match, not the lack of. I'm very new to awk as well so if you could breakdown your response for me I'd really appreciate it.

Let me know if anything isn't clear, or if there's a thread that covers this!

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '
NR==FNR { a[$1]=$0; next;}
$1 in a { delete a[$1]; print;}
END { for (key in a){print a[key]} }
' file1 file2
```

**Explanation:**

`NR==FNR { a[$1]=$0; next;}`
Create array from File1(NR==FNR), where key is first column($1) and value is whole line($0).

`$1 in a { delete a[$1]; print;}` Match File2 with previously created array, delete entry and print line.

`END { for (key in a){print a[key]} }` Print every remaining entry in the array.

**Writing output to file2:**

```
temp=$(mktemp)
awk '...' file1 file2 > "$temp"
mv "$temp" file2
```

You shouldn't write to file2 in place, just create temporary file and then move it to file2 path.